# Javascript logic not flowing as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing the following logic to determine the current page and fetch the page_number from the current page - but although I correctly obtain the current page URL, when I modify it, the value seems to be reset to `undefined`.

I think this may be a scope resolution error, but declaring the variable `new_page` using `var` instead of `let` does not seem to resolve the issue.

I know I am overlooking something trivial - but I can't, for the life of me, spot it.

Here is my code:

```
$().ready(function(e){
  $('button#ghead-submit').on('click', function(e){
    let val = $('input.sort-order[name=rdoMystuff]:checked').val()
    let url = window.location.href; 

    console.log(url);

    let page_number = 1
    let new_page;
    
    if (url.includes('?page=')){
      console.log('true');
      let temp = url.split('?page=');
      let page_number = parseInt(temp[1]);
      new_page = `${temp[0]}${page_number}`;
      console.log(new_page);  /* correct out put here */
    }
    else {
      console.log('false');
      new_page = `${new_page}?page=1`;
      console.log(new_page);  /* correct out put here */
    }

    alert(val);
    alert(new_page);  /* output as 'undefined'! */
  })
});
```

Comment: Could you please create a [mre]?

Comment: Does that mean  that the code above works for you?

Comment: Did you read the link? It means that there is no way for us to run the code, and therefore almost impossible to help you...

Comment: lol can't run it, but wouldn't temp[0] only be part of the url, not including ?page=

Comment: Your debugging logs and alerts (and `alert()` is a bad idea) should include some additional text so that you know exactly what's going on, like `console.log("new_page at end of click handler: " + new_page);` instead of just the variable.

Comment: are you sure `alert(new_page); ` showing  `undefined`  not `alert(val);` see it --- https://codepen.io/sbrakeshrath/pen/JjNKbyR?editors=1111

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare `page_number` twice. Thus, it's undefined in the upper scope (outside of the `if`) which is why your result is undefined as well.

```js
let page_number = 1                      // <-- You declare page_number here
let new_page;                            //  |
                                         //  |
if (url.includes('?page=')){             //  |
    console.log('true');                 //  |
    let temp = url.split('?page=');      //  |
    let page_number = parseInt(temp[1]); // <-- you declare it here again. 
    new_page = `${temp[0]}${page_number}`;
    console.log(new_page);  /* correct out put here */
}
```

Remove the `let` before `page_number` in the if block.

Comment: I think you mean that `page_number` is **declared** twice.

Comment: Ah, yes, good catch. Also, I should be initialising `new_page` variable to `url` variable. These two fixes resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're re-declaring the variable `page_number` inside the first if-statement.

```js
$().ready(function(e){
  $('button#ghead-submit').on('click', function(e){
    let val = $('input.sort-order[name=rdoMystuff]:checked').val()
    let url = window.location.href; 

    console.log(url);

    let page_number = 1
    let new_page;
    
    if (url.includes('?page=')){
      console.log('true');
      let temp = url.split('?page=');
      let page_number = parseInt(temp[1]); // here, you can remove the "let"
      new_page = `${temp[0]}${page_number}`;
      console.log(new_page);  /* correct out put here */
    }
    else {
      console.log('false');
      new_page = `${new_page}?page=1`;
      console.log(new_page);  /* correct out put here */
    }

    alert(val);
    alert(new_page);  /* output as 'undefined'! */
  })
});
```